# Constructor on type 'GTS.CSVImport_HR_Standard' not found

Tags: c#

I have the following C# class and 2 constructors:

```
public class CSVImport_HR_Standard : CSVImport
{
    int fPropertyID;

    public CSVImport_HR_Standard()
    {
    }

    public CSVImport_HR_Standard(string oActivationParams)
    {
        this.fPropertyID = Convert.ToInt32(oActivationParams);
    }
```

And the parent class:

```
public class CSVImport
{
```

Without any constructors.

The class is being called from the following method:

```
    private object CreateCommandClassInstance(string pCommandClass, string pActivationParams.ToArray())
    {
        List<object> oActivationParams = new List<object>();
        // In the current implementation we assume only one param of type int
        if (pActivationParams != "")
        {
            Int32 iParam = Convert.ToInt32(pActivationParams);

            oActivationParams.Add(iParam);
        }


        object oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("GTS." + pCommandClass), oActivationParams);

        return(oObject);
    }
```

Where

```
pCommandClass = GTS.CSVImport_HR_Standard
```

But I get the following error:

```
Constructor on type 'GTS.CSVImport_HR_Standard' not found. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'GTS.CSVImport_HR_Standard' not found.
```

As far as I can see the constructor is correct and it is passing in all the correct parameters, so why is it giving me this error?

From what I have read, my best guess would be that it is something to do with the line:

```
    object oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("GTS." + pCommandClass), oActivationParams);
```

But I am not sure what could be causing a problem as it seems the constructor is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the use of a `List<object>` as second parameter in the `CreateInstance` method. This makes the method search for a constructor with signature `(List<object>)`, rather then the types of the elements inside.

You have to call `ToArray` in order to call the right overload of that method (it now calls the :

```
object oObject = Activator.CreateInstance( Type.GetType("GTS." + pCommandClass)
                                         , oActivationParams.ToArray()
                                         );
```

Also, make sure to use `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pActivationParams))` instead of `if (pActivationParams != "")`.

Comment: Did you try my last note? Try set `pActivationParams` to `null`.

Comment: yes I tried using ToArray and also changed the constructor to receive an array but it still gives the same error

Comment: Where in my answer did I tell to change the constructor?

Comment: you didnt but the original case before I posted was exactly as you suggested in your answer, so I have been experimenting with different variations

Answer (score 0):

The problem was it was turning the array into a list of arguments and passing them in individually.

To solve I did the following with the constructor:

```
    public CSVImport_HR_Standard(params object[] oActivationParams)
    {
        this.fPropertyID = Convert.ToInt32(oActivationParams[0]);
    }
```

and passed in as follows:

```
 object oObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("GTS." + pCommandClass), oActivationParams.ToArray());
```

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use `params`? There seems no use in it since you pass an array to the `CreateInstance` method...

Comment: If you want to use the constructor with `string oActivationParams`, you need to pass in a `string`, and not convert it to an integer in your `CreateCommandClassInstance` method.

Comment: @PatrickHofman this is existing software and all the parts except for the constructor are being used by other parts of the application, therefore I cannnot change anything and this is the only way I could get it to work. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: But you don't have to change the constructor. Did you see the fiddle I provided? It does work.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I know it works, but there must be something in my project that is stopping it from working in there